# Install Visual Studio on Windows Thin PC

Tags: windows, installation, visual-studio-2010

Can I install Visual studio 2010 on Windows 7 Thin PC?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to. Typically it will be installed on a VM that you RDP into with the Thin PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not [according to Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/ultimate/system-requirements):

> Visual Studio 2010 can be installed on the following operating
>   systems:
>
> - Windows XP (x86) with Service Pack 3 - all editions except Starter Edition
> - Windows Vista (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2 - all editions except Starter Edition
> - Windows 7 (x86 & x64)
> - Windows Server 2003 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2
> - Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86 & x64)
> - Windows Server 2008 (x86 & x64) with Service Pack 2
> - Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64)